# Twitter Web Intents - Load widget.js on Demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am currently using Twitter Web Intents on my site and load it traditionally by including

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

on the page and then subsequently attach event listeners like this:

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  // bind events here
});
```

This works great, but I would ideally like to load the `widget.js` on demand only, i.e. only when the user clicks my Twitter button.

Ideally, I would like the following workflow:

- Include Twitter button in HTML
- Attach my own click handler to the button
- On click, I load the `widget.js` asynchronously
- On successful load, I immediately follow the usual tweet behavior (i.e. open the Twitter popup)

Right now, as soon as `widget.js` gets loaded, it attaches its click handler to the Twitter button and I am not aware of a way to trigger that handler automatically.

Any ideas/tips?

Comment: your workflow sounds good except you could use a placeholder button to inject the twitter script into the page, and swap it out or hide the old one when the new one arrives (in twttr.ready) .

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it would require 2 clicks to initiate the tweet - one on the placeholder button and then one on the real one.  I want to collapse it to just a single click.

Comment: just call .click() on the twittr button once it gets added by your injector...

Comment: Steve did you find a way to work this out? if yes then share :)